# Small loop over pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can you help me with this problem please.
So, I have a pandas data frame containing conversations identified by ID’s.
For each conversation We have the interaction Number between the interlocutors.
There are also two Boolean variables: the first one (Answer) indicates if the sentence is an Answer and the second one (Question) indicates if the sentence is a Question.
I’d like to do a loop on that table to determine the average on which position comes the answer (variable Interaction_Number) and after how many positions comes the answer following the question.
For this example: The answer comes in average after (3+2+4)/3=3 interactions and it comes in average (1+1+1)/3=1 position following the question.
Thank you for helping.

| ID | Sentences | Interaction_Number | Answer | Question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hi my name is John | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | How are you ? | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | I’m good thanks | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Hi what can I do for you? | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | I’d like to order a pizza | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Hi sir | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | Hi | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | What can I do for you? | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | I’d like to have a coffee | 4 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: First, "tricky" in title does not describe your problem. Please change the question title. Second, please post the code you did.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, use:

```
df[(df['Answer']==1)&(df['Interaction_Number']>0)]['Interaction_Number'].mean()
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

For the second part, use:

```
df.shift(-1)[(df['Answer'].shift(-1)==1)&(df['Question']==1)]['Answer'].mean()
```

Output:

```
1.0
```